# Can newsfeeds be versioned in Plone?

Tags: plone, feed

Articles in Plone go through an author-editor-publisher process. Why are feeds the exception? Is there a way to do this with feeds/news through the adding a news item process?

Comment: With feeds, do you mean external RSS feeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feeds follow the same pattern; they will pick up on whatever criteria you have specified in e.g. a Collection. If you only show things that are "Published", that will also be the case in the associated feed.

If you're asking for a separate workflow/approval process for the feed itself, that's not how it works. (And I have problems seeing what kind of problem it would solve outside of adding more complexity and more process :)